# Finding processes using ALSA sound fast

Tags: linux, shell, audio, posix, alsa

Currently the way `/usr/sbin/alsa` in Debian knows the processes using the sound card looks like:

```
echo $( \
    lsof +D /dev -F rt \
    | awk '/^p/ {pid=$1} /^t/ {type=$1} /^r0x(74|e)..$/ && type == "tCHR" {print pid}' \
    | cut -c 2- \
    | uniq \
)
```

Which is rather ugly and depends on `lsof`. I am looking for a POSIX solution without `lsof`, perhaps using /proc.

```
    time for i in /proc/*/fd/*; do readlink $i | grep -q /dev/snd/pcm && echo $i | awk -F '/' '{print $3}'; done | uniq
```

Unfortunately seems to take twice as long as the `lsof` based snippet above. Can you make it faster, in order to make it a viable replacement?

**Update** I rewrote the above as:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/fd/*
do
        if readlink $i | grep -q /dev/snd/pcm
        then
                IFS=/; set -- $i; unset IFS; echo $3
        fi
done
```

But it seems to have the same performance as my earlier snippet. I suspect grep is the culprit.

Update:  I have opened a [Debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=514661) on the topic.

Comment: /proc is not part of POSIX, as far as I know.

Comment: When I say POSIX, I mean the shell code should be able to run on any shell like dash for example.

Comment: /bin/posh -- is what I meant :}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start a lot of processes here.  Instead you can try doing in a similar way to the lsof script you posted... but replacing lsof by a shell for loop:

If you want to avoid launching lots of grep processes, start only one:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/fd/*
do
    echo ${i%/fd/*} $(readlink $i)
done | grep -q /dev/snd/pcm
```

This takes now 4.5s on my desktop, compared to 7.5s when there's one grep process for each opened file.

But... your grep is not necessary here, I think. If you care so much, you can try:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/fd/*
do
    var="$(readlink $i)"
    if test x"$var" != x"${var#/dev/snd/pcm}"
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

This is even faster for me (`test` is almost always a shell builtin), but I guess this is more because of bad testing methods. Try yourself.

Comment: That code is 3x faster on my tests. Great thank you! I've wrongly avoided parameter expansion.

Answer (score 16):

There is an answer for this question on the [ALSA FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20090201162847/http://alsa.opensrc.org/index.php/FAQ#How_can_I_find_which_processes_are_using_Alsa_devices.3F). On my system, using fuser is way faster than using lsof.

```
fuser -v /dev/snd/*
```

Comment: `fuser` is fast, but it depends on [psmisc](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/psmisc.html). I'm trying to shed dependencies, not replace with another. :-)

Comment: ALSA FAQ link is broken.

Comment: The FAQ URL I posted 5 years ago was from an unofficial FAQ which unfortunately does not exist anymore. This is how it looked like in 2009: https://web.archive.org/web/20090201162847/http://alsa.opensrc.org/index.php/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what kind of timescales you're looking for but for your alternative suggestion

```
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/fd/*;
```

might work and give you a bit of speed up, as might using `cut` rather than `awk`.